# Unable to declare and access a List for a live search functionality

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

as the title says I am new to C# and I am currently having trouble making this script work.

It is supposed to define a List with some dummy text and for searching purposes.

Here is the code:

```
@page "/livesearch"
@using System.Collections.Generic

<input @bind-value="SearchTerm" @bind-value:event="oninput" />

<span class="text-muted ml-5">
    Showing @FilteredToDos.Count out of @ToDoItems.Count
</span>

<h4 class="mt-4">To Do's</h4>
<ul>
    @foreach (var toDo in FilteredToDos)
    {
        <li>@toDo.Name</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    // Initialize SearchTerm to "" to prevent null's
    string SearchTerm { get; set; } = "";

    // Imagine this was retrieved from an API, just hardcoding for demo purposes
        List<string> items = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "foobar" };

    List<items> FilteredToDos => items.Where(i => i.0.ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm.ToLower())).ToList();
}
```

The problem is coming from the last line, namely from `items` in `List<items> FilteredToDos` and the `i.0.ToLower()` part.

The error says

> The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Update with screenshot:
[image]

Comment: `i.0.ToLower()` doesn't valid in syntax. Probably you mean `i.ToLower()`.

Comment: FYI `i.ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm.ToLower())` can be "simplified" to `i.Contains(SearchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` (it's longer, but clearer at communicating what's going on to a reader)

Comment: Thanks, I added a screenshot, i still get errors

Comment: And another issue is unmatch type, you can't assign a `List<string>` value to `FilteredToDos` which is `List of object` type. Your `items` should be `List of object` type which match the `FilteredToDos` type. And also you miss out `items` class as error highlight in `List<items>`.

Comment: Can you please check the first code in this page: https://scottsauber.com/2019/03/25/blazor-implementing-client-side-search-as-you-type-using-bind-value-oninput/ That is where my script is from but I need to declare somehow an empty object for it to work (above line 22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues in your attached code besides the `i.0`,

**Issues:**

1. `items` class is missing.
2. You can't assign a `List<string>` value to the variable of `List</* class */>` type.

**Solution**:

1. Declare a `ToDoItem` class.

```cs
public class ToDoItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2.1. `items` should be `List<ToDoItem>` type.

2.2. Filter by `item.Name` that contains `SearchTerm` (suggested by @MindSwipe to work with `string.Contains()` ignore case sensitive).

```cs
List<ToDoItem> items = new List<ToDoItem>() 
{ 
    new ToDoItem { Name = "foo" }, 
    new ToDoItem { Name = "bar" }, 
    new ToDoItem { Name = "foobar" }
};

List<ToDoItem> FilteredToDos => items
    .Where(i => i.Name.Contains(SearchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToList();
```